# Cross Compile GMP and Openswan for ARM

Tags: ubuntu, arm, cross-compilation

I have to cross compile `opensawn` for a OMAP4 Board and GMP is prerequisite. First I tried it on 64 bit OS but it gave me this error:

> configure: error: Oops, mp_limb_t is 64 bits, but the assembler code in this configuration expects 32 bits.

Then I shifted to Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit and the GMP V6.0.0 got compiled after few trials. Even after having the ARCH, TOOLCHAIN and CROSS_COMPILER variables in `.bashrc` I had to `export` the following:

```
export ARCH=arm<BR>
export PATH=/home/harsh32bit/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/BISQUARE/gcc-SourceryCodeBenchLite-arm/bin/:$PATH<BR>
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-<BR>
```

Then following commands were observed:

```
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/harsh32bit/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/BISQUARE/gcc-SourceryCodeBenchLite-arm/

make clean
make
make install
```

Then Soft-linking GMP Library to Toolchain

```
~/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/BISQUARE/gcc-SourceryCodeBenchLite-arm/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3  
# ln -s ~/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/packages/gmp-6.0.0/.libs/libgmp.so libgmp.so
```

I had the GMP compiled successfully although the `make check` reported all test failed.

```
9 of 9 tests failed.
```

Now when I try to cross compile Openswan-2.6.41 after making changes in CROSSCOMPILE.sh and do this `make programs` I get this error:

> In file included from /home/harsh32bit/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/packages/openswan-2.6.41/include/certs.h:24:0,from /home/harsh32bit/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/packages/openswan-2.6.41/lib/libopenswan/id.c:42:
>       /home/harsh32bit/Work/Projects/BSQ_VVDN/packages/openswan-2.6.41/include/secrets.h:20:41: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
>       compilation terminated

I need to cross compile `openswan` and `GMP`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was taking a lot of time so I took an hunch and thought of compiling it on the OMAP4 board itself instead of cross compiling it on ubuntu. Lucky for me that the OMAP4 board was powerful enough to carry out such compilations: That awesome feeling, if anyone understands.